# Calculate P-Value

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

In a certain area, regulations require that the chlorine level in
wastewater discharges be less than 100 $\mu$/L. In a sample of 85 wastewater
specimens, the mean chlorine concentration was 98 $\mu$g/L and the standard
deviation was 20 /L. Let $\mu$ represent the mean chlorine level. A test is made of
$$H_0:\mu \ge 100$$$$ H_1:\mu \lt 100$$
Find the p-value.

I'm not really sure how to do it because my teacher is hard to understand. But this is my attempt from learning by what he wrote.

$n = 100, \mu = 98, \sigma = 20$

Since n is sufficiently large, we can find the Z-score.
$$z = \frac{\sqrt{n}(X- \mu_0)}{\sigma} = -.922$$
$$p\{Z<-.922\} \implies 1-p\{z < .922\} \implies 1-\phi(.922)=.1782$$
$\phi(.922)$ was obtained from using a table

Assuming a 95%level of significance, the it is not plausible because $.1782 > .05$ which means we reject the null hypothesis. There is strong evidence against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with some confusion about notation and terminology, you 
are on the right track. Here is a corrected version of what you have.

You want $Z = \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu_0)}{\sigma}
 = \frac{\sqrt{85}(98-100)}{20} = -0.922.$

From normal tables $P(Z < -0.922) \approx 0.1783.$ This is the
P-value. Because the P-value exceeds 5% we do not to reject.

(Your 95% might be for a confidence interval, but 5% is a
reasonable significance level for a test of hypothesis.)

Comment: I didn't realize I could use \bar some other notations must be class-specific for my class. But thank you very much

Comment: OK, but note: $n \ne 100$ and $\bar X = 98,$ not $\mu.$